# Bash : for i in *.xls return one result even if there is not xls's files

Tags: bash, for-loop, glob

I've got an **empty** directory. The command:

```
for i in *.xls; do echo $i; done
```

return

```
*.xls
```

Could you explain why? And how to correct this please?

Thanks

Comment: "Why" is so `ls *.xls` says `*.xls: file not found` instead of doing the same thing as `ls` with no arguments and listing every file in the current directory (not just `.xls` files).

Comment: "How do avoid it" is covered by the linked duplicate (there are two approaches: `shopt -s nullglob` to change behavior, or making your loop run something like `[[ -e $i || -L $i ]] || continue`). There's also a `failglob` flag you can set to make a glob that doesn't match anything be an error.

Comment: I highly suggest failglob when interactive. Nullglob when not.